# Git Merge: Remove unnecessary file/folder

Tags: git

```
git merge
```

I'm trying to merge my dev branch to master, but I don't want to merge some of the files/folders to master branch, because it is not needed now on Master.

Comment: Merge first, then remove the unwanted files and folders and make a commit.

Comment: So after merge to Master. Remove files from Master branch & then commit. Correct @ElpieKay

Answer (score 2):

Create a second branch for your git repository, then push your repository on the second one. Then delete the files you don't need on master and merge the second branch with master

Answer (score 1):

guessing file you are talking about are committed already.

```
git rm yourfile.txt
git commit -m "remove yourfile.txt"
```

and then push your changes to branch

```
git push origin branch_name
```

and then merge with your master branch.

> Note: for the directory use--> git rm -r somedirName

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar trick (but in reverse) to that given in [How to make Git preserve specific files while merging](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b) where you could `.gitattribute` the file, and then create a merge driver that simply removes its content.

This will depend on whether you want the file gone from the commit or an empty content to be still present. It also presumes that these are well known files that can be picked up by the `.gitattribute`s settings. Otherwise, simply do a clean up commit that removes those unwanted files/directories before the merge.

Comment: I've asked about singleton files that are not wanted on the Git devs list https://public-inbox.org/git/8CEDDC40C7D24404976929CF3E7AF6FC@PhilipOakley/ Let's see if there is an even better answer.